# get a value in a database based on select-statement

Tags: sql-server, select

Sorry for my question-title, I couldn't find a better name for it.

This is my table:

```
Project_ID   ParentProject   Projecttype
----------------------------------------
20.003       20.001          P
20.001       20              P
20           NULL            V
21.001       21              P
21           NULL            V
```

I want to make a selection of all my projects with it's 'upperparentproject'. I want to search for all Projects with `Projecttype = 'P'` a `ParentProject` with `Projecttype = 'V'`. So this has to be my result:

```
Project_ID   ParentProject
--------------------------
20.003       20        
20.001       20                
21.001       21
```

Is this possible in a `SELECT` statement or is there another way to perform this?

Comment: You can use the recursive CTE to achieve this. But recursive CTE will perform worst if your table is bit larger.

Comment: It's quite a big table indeed (11000 rows), can you give me an example of recursive CTE using my example-table?

Comment: Refer this link for recursive CTE http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/ -- I will post the answer when I get time. I'm bit busy now :(

Comment: Thanks, I found that article earlier today. Unfortunately all the examples I'm finding are about getting data of it's PARENT, not it's grandparent or grandgrandparent or deeper. That's not working for me because sometimes the data I need is 2 level or deeper above it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 select *,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as rn  into tbl1 from table1

Declare @mn int,@mx int
Declare @mn1 int,@mx1 int
Declare @prjid float,@prntid varchar(10)
DECLARE @result TABLE(prjID float,prentID varchar(10))

select @mn=MIN(rn),@mx=MAX(rn) from tbl1

WHILE(@mn<=@mx)
BEGIN
select @prjid=Project_id,@prntid=ParentProject from tbl1 where rn=@mn and ProjectType='P'
select @mn1=MIN(rn),@mx1=MAX(rn) from tbl1

WHILE(@mn1<=@mx1)
BEGIN
select @prntid=CASE WHEN ParentProject IS NOT NULL then ParentProject else @prntid end from tbl1 where Project_id=@prntid and rn = @mn1
SET @mn1=@mn1+1
END

INSERT INTO @result 
values(@prjid,@prntid) 

SET @mn=@mn+1
END
select distinct * from @result
```

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question, but I have never worked befor with over/into: What is the defenition of 'table1' in the first lin of your code? When I try the query on my own database, that's where I got stuck

Comment: Hey I am just copying your main table into another table tbl1 with sequence number. ROW_NUMBER() is used to generate the number sequence like identity column.

Comment: Here you replace table1 with your actual table

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008, I get the following error: Msg 2705, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'rn' in table 'tbl1' is specified more than once.

Comment: is there any column named rn in your main table?

Comment: and you just execute the first line just once in your db seperately

Comment: Column name did exist indeed, I changed it. My query is now executing for almost 50 minutes, I think this has something to do with my large number of rows, don't think this is going to work for me